# Changing one coefficient in a set of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a set of linear equations described by $A\vec{X}=\vec{B}$ is given, where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $\vec{X}$ and $\vec{B}$ are n-row vectors. Also suppose that this system of equations have a unique solution and this solution is given.

Imagine a new set of linear equations $A'\vec{X}=\vec{B}$, where all elements of $A'$ is equal to those of $A$ but one element $A_{ij}$ which is increased by $k$. I am interested to know if I could somehow relate the solution of the first problem to the second problem by knowing the value of $k$ and $A$. In other words, I would like to derive the new solution without resolving the set of linear equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the $3\times 3$ case when $a_{21}$ is changed by $+k$.  The determinant $\det(A)$ is in every entry in $A^{-1}$, so let's look at that.  Expand along the second row to see that $\det(A + k e_{21}) = -(a_{21} + k)|C_{21}| + a_{22} |C_{22}| - a_{23}|C_{23}|$ where $|C_{ik}|$ is the determinant of the matrix $A$ with row $i$ and column $k$ deleted, a $2\times 2$ matrix.  This formula equals $det(A) + (-1)^{i+j}k|C_{ij}|$.

Answer (score 1):

Changing a single element corresponds to a special rank one update of the form
$$(a'(i,j)-a(i,j))e_i e_j^T$$where $e_k$ is a vector with zero except at location $k$, which is one. You can use [Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) to construct the solution for low-rank updates.